# Is it safe to call setBadgeIdentifier:forURL: for files that have not been displayed in the OSX finder?

Tags: macos, findersync

For the OS X FIFinderSyncController the documentation for setBadgeIdentifier:forURL: says:

> Avoid adding badges to items that have not been displayed in the Finder.

Does anybody know if it cause any problems if it is called for items that have not been displayed in the Finder?

It required a fair bit of work for the finder extension to keep track of all items seen by the finder and then only update the badge identifiers for those items. It is far simpler to notify the finder of  change to a any badge identifier and have the finder ignore the call if it has not been seen.

I am not planning on calling setBadgeIdentifier for all items in the monitored folder on startup but to just call it when something happens such that the badge identifier would change.

Answer (score 0):

The full quote is:

> Avoid adding badges to items that have not been displayed in the Finder. When setting the initial badge, call this method from your Finder Sync extension’s requestBadgeIdentifierForURL: method. When updating badges, call this method only for items that have already received a badge.

The docs for `requestBadgeIdentifierForURL:` state:

> Override this method to receive notifications **whenever a new item becomes visible in the Finder**. Check the item’s state, and set an appropriate badge.

So I believe the "not been displayed in the Finder" advice means that you should 
be using the notifications from `requestBadgeIdentifierForURL:` whenever an item appears in Finder. Avoid adding badges otherwise.